# Is it possible to convert WebAssembly to LLVM?

Tags: llvm, webassembly

I've made [a compiler for my programming language that outputs WebAssembly Text Format](https://aecforwebassembly.sourceforge.io/), and it uses the `wat2wasm` assembler from WebAssembly Binary Toolkit to convert it to WebAssembly. I am interested, can I somehow convert WebAssembly to LLVM in order to make native executables, or do I need to write a new compiler in order to target LLVM?

As far as I know, WebAssembly corresponds very closely to LLVM, so it should be possible to convert WebAssembly to LLVM. LLVM supports everything WebAssembly does plus a lot more (`goto` statements...). Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: Sure it's possible! Might not be easy though. (I'm VTCing this question due to lacking objective design criterion. Of course it's _possible_ to do this, but we can't help you unless you're having a specific problem doing it.)

Comment: If the question is reopened, it should be rephrased to LLVM IR, because that's what it is about.

Comment: A more objective question could be something like, "does WebAssembly correspond to a subset of LLVM IR?" or "does WebAssembly have any instructions which don't have analogues in LLVM IR?"

Comment: *"[...] or do I need to write a new compiler in order to target LLVM?"* Usually you wouldn't write an entirely new compiler. You would just have one compiler that, internally, has two *backends*: One that produces WebAssembly and one that produces LLVM IR. This is the approach I would suggest, rather than trying to convert between the two. The multiple backend approach solves the problem directly. And you also wouldn't need to worry if your WebAsm -> LLVM IR translation is correct (which actually could be a pretty major concern, otherwise)!