# Does WebAssembly have any instructions which don't have analogues in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, webassembly

I know EMSCRIPTEN can convert from LLVM IR to WebAssembly, but I don't know of any tool that converts from WebAssembly to LLVM IR. Such a tool would come useful to me, as [the compiler for my programming language outputs WebAssembly](https://aecforwebassembly.sourceforge.io), and I would like to be able to make native ARM executables. Why doesn't such a tool exist? Is converting WebAssembly to LLVM IR, for some reason, much more complicated than doing what EMSCRIPTEN does?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question, because there is no reason to even assume that you couldn't compile WebAssembly to LLVM IR. The question is rather, how much runtime would be required to reflect WebAssembly semantics wrt. to e.g. memory management. Last time I checked the WebAssembly specification, such aspects were still quite unclear.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this other question you asked](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/3007/89) which was closed. When one of your questions is closed and you want to fix it, you should edit it, not post a new one. Unfortunately this is still all over the place (you're asking about instructions, whether anyone knows of a conversion tool, why such a tool doesn't exist, and if converting is complicated).

Comment: I think if the question actually matched the title it would be a good, focused, stand-alone question.

Comment: You may want to check out WASI